# Is it possible to automatically and implicitly add filters to a query?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm dealing with a DB (not managed by me) with a bunch of tables where each entry has a couple columns (`valid_from` and `valid until`) denoting a timespan during which this entry was or is valid. The most recent entry always has `valid_until` set to something in the year 5000. I'm only interested in the latest entries, so in each query I have to add a filter along the lines of `XXX.valid_until > func.getdate()` (mssql) for each table that participates in the query. Also I haven't found a way to define relationships between the tables because I always have to somehow take the validity period into account.

Question: Is it possible to implicitly automate this? This would have to be on the Query level, so my ORM session would need some augmented `.query_latest()` method so that this call

```
rs = db.query_latest(Foo)
```

would be equivalent to this:

```
rs = db.query(Foo).filter(Foo.valid_until > func.getdate())
```

This isn't big enough a deal to actually spend much time on, I just thought that if there were an elegant way to deal with this I'd be interested to further my understanding of SQLAlchemy. If it turns out to require a convoluted mess nobody understands a few months from now I won't bother.

Answer (score 0):

So write a function:

```
def query_latest(db, table):
    return db.query(table).filter(table.valid_until > func.getdate())


query_latest(db, Foo)
```

Add it to db if you really want to, but I would leave it as a free function.

```
setattr(db, "query_latest", query_latest)
```

I think I would do like:

```
def my_filter(table):
   return table.valid_until > func.getdate()

db.query(Foo).filter(my_filter(Foo))
```

Comment: The latest idea (my_filter) is what I am currently doing, but of course I need to remember to add it for each table in a joined query.

Answer (score 0):

You can write generic function to query objects with filter:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

ModelT = TypeVar("ModelT")

def query_latest(db, model: Type[ModelT]) -> list[ModelT]:
    return db.query(model).filter(model.valid_until > func.getdate())
```

And then you can use this function with different models. But all of them have to have `valid_until` field of right type.

```
res = query_latest(db, Foo)
```

If you need the possibility to add additional filters when you query objects, you can go another way (this example uses SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM style):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
from sqlalchemy import select, Select

ModelT = TypeVar("ModelT")

def query_latest(model: Type[ModelT]) -> Select[ModelT]:
    return select(model).filter(model.valid_until > func.getdate())

# in this implementation you can add additional filters, like 'filter(Foo.id > 1000)'
res = session.scalars(query_latest(Foo).filter(Foo.id > 1000)).all()
```